# Stuck in a golf game code of a freecodecamp

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve the Golf Code challenge in freecodecamp and I can't really figure out what is wrong with my code here is the direct link. [The link][1] contains the code I am trying to run, just visit the link.

**My JS:**

```js
const names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"];

function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  // Only change code below this line
  var msg=names;
  
  switch(par,strokes){
    case strokes=1:
      msg=names[0];
      break;
    case strokes <= par -2:
      msg=names[1];
      break;
    case strokes=par-1:
      msg=names[2];
      break;
    case strokes=par:
      msg=names[3];
      break;
    case strokes=par+1:
      msg=names[4];
      break;
    case strokes=par+2:
      msg=names[5];
      break;
    case strokes >= par +3:
      msg=names[6];
      break;
  }

  return msg;
  // Only change code above this line
}

golfScore(5, 4);
```

**Requirement:**

Passed:golfScore(4, 1) should return the string Hole-in-one!

**Failed:golfScore(4, 2) should return the string Eagle**

**Failed:golfScore(5, 2) should return the string Eagle**

Passed:golfScore(4, 3) should return the string Birdie

Passed:golfScore(4, 4) should return the string Par

Passed:golfScore(1, 1) should return the string Hole-in-one!

Passed:golfScore(5, 5) should return the string Par

Passed:golfScore(4, 5) should return the string Bogey

Passed:golfScore(4, 6) should return the string Double Bogey

**Failed:golfScore(4, 7) should return the string Go Home!**

**Failed:golfScore(5, 9) should return the string Go Home!**

Strokes Return: 1                 "Hole-in-one!"

```
           <= par - 2         "Eagle"

           par - 1            "Birdie"

           par                "Par"

           par + 1            "Bogey"

           par + 2            "Double Bogey"

           >= par + 3         "Go Home!"
```

Actually, I found the solutions in 'if else()' but, I am trying with 'switch()' as well but those **bold requirements** are not being a success.
[1]: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/basic-javascript/golf-code

Comment: You have misunderstood how `switch` statements work.

Comment: @Pointy think it has more to do with doing assignments instead of comparisons. Need to replace `=` with `===`.

Comment: @JaredSmith well there's a lot to talk about, that's certainly true.

Comment: You should put some effort into learning about how JavaScript expressions and statements work. This code is seriously incorrect.

Comment: @JaredSmith sir, where should I use '===' instead of '=' all the conditions are working expect those '<=  >=' operations  though!

Comment: @DUMREANUP `=` is for assignment `const foo = 3;` binds the value 3 to the name foo. But for comparison you want `===`: the comparison `3 === 4` is false, `'a' === 'a'` is true, etc. Greater than or equal two and less than or equal to are the same as their mathematical formulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Switch` statement doesn't really works with multiple variables.
So I do prefer @NijatMusali answer.

If you absolutely want to use the `switch` clause, here is a way to do it:

```js
switch(true) { // This the value the 'case' expression will be compared to, so use the case block only if the expression is true
    case strokes===1: // Change assignations `=` to comparison `===` 
      msg=names[0];
      break;
    case strokes <= par -2:
      msg=names[1];
      break;
    case strokes===par-1:
      msg=names[2];
      break;
    case strokes===par:
      msg=names[3];
      break;
    case strokes===par+1:
      msg=names[4];
      break;
    case strokes===par+2:
      msg=names[5];
      break;
    case strokes >= par +3:
      msg=names[6];
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to check how [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement exactly works, I think you misunderstood it. I think the idea of that is to use [if-else statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
.

In that case, you might check the cases easily by `if` and `else-if`

like

```js
var names = ["Hole-in-one!", "Eagle", "Birdie", "Par", "Bogey", "Double Bogey", "Go Home!"]

function golfScore(par, strokes) {
  if (strokes === 1) return names[0];
  else if (strokes <= par - 2) return names[1];
  else if (strokes === par - 1) return names[2];
  else if (strokes === par) return names[3];
  else if (strokes === par + 1) return names[4];
  else if (strokes === par + 2) return names[5];
  else if (strokes >= par + 3) return names[6];
}

let result = golfScore(5, 2);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: should `strokes => par + 3` have `>=` instead?

Comment: yes, indeed. Thanks for noting.